# Error when inserting to table more than once

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle10g

I have a VB.NET application that, as a part of this function, writes to an oracle database. When I launch the application the works perfectly fine for one iteration but, while the application is still open, if I attempt to write to the database again I get the following error.

```
 ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'INSERTINTORACOSENT'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

And my Procedure in Oracle SQL is

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE     insertintoracosent(
    p_phone            IN RACOSENT.PHONE%TYPE,
    p_msg              IN RACOSENT.MESSAGE%TYPE)
IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO racosent
  VALUES (seq_sent.nextval, p_phone, p_msg, sysdate);
END;
```

My VB.NET code is

```
 Sub orclSendSMS(ByRef cbManNum As String, ByRef cbManMsg As String)
    If orcl.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then orcl.Open()
    myCMD.Connection = orcl
    myCMD.CommandText = "insertintoracosent"
    myCMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    Dim num As OracleParameter = New OracleParameter("p_phone", OracleDbType.Int64, ParameterDirection.Input)
    Dim msg As OracleParameter = New OracleParameter("p_msg", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input)
    num.Value = Convert.ToInt64(cbManNum)
    msg.Value = cbManMsg
    myCMD.Parameters.Add(num)
    myCMD.Parameters.Add(msg)
    Try
        myCMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        Exit Sub
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Wasn't aware that it was needed but have since added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you may not be re-initialising myCMD? So the number of parameters in the parameters collection goes up by two each time?

Try doing a `myCMD.Parameters.Count`

Comment: Thanks. I'm still new to OracleDataAccess and wasn't sure what was going wrong.